# adding ssh key to a user from a bash script being run as root

Tags: linux, git, bash, ssh

I want to give a user access to a git repository without him having to enter a password.

Lets say I have a bash script that does this:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This script is being run with sudo ./script.sh
I would I add the ssh key for a user instead of root?

Comment: Pretty soon, you're going to have a bajillion `ssh-agent` processes running and not really doing anything, unless your script is also careful to terminate that process when it's done (or you have a second script that does cleanup for you).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `su -c <command> $SUID_USER` with your commands.

Comment: Like this: su -c "eval `ssh-agent -s` ssh-add $HOMEDIR/.ssh/id_rsa" $USERNAME ? This won't work.